# Html Highlighting text with onmouseover when the text is created by button using onclick

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, onmouseover

I am generating text after a user enters their name

I want to be able to highlight the output of the entername() function. I'm able to highlight text but unsure how to do it to this specified output?

```js
function entername() {
  var user = document.getElementById("username").value;
  document.body.append("Hey " + user);
}

function overgreeting() {
  document.getElementById("content").style.backgroundColor = "green";
}
```

```html
<main>

  <input type="string" name="name" id="username">
  <button title="Greet" onclick="entername()">
            Greet
        </button>


  <button onmouseover="overgreeting()"> Test Button </button>
  <p id="content" onmouseover="entername"> </p

</main>
```

Comment: You do not have anything called  "content"

Comment: Apologies, added the relevant code.

Comment: You are missing () on `onmouseover="entername()"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean this?

```js
function entername() {
  var user = document.getElementById("username").value;
  document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = 'Hey ' + user;
}

function overgreeting() {
  document.getElementById("content").style.backgroundColor = "green";
}
```

```css
#content {
  background-color: yellow
}
```

```html
<main>

  <input type="string" name="name" id="username">
  <button title="Greet" onclick="entername()">
            Greet
        </button>


  <button onmouseover="overgreeting()"> Test Button </button>
  <p id="content" onmouseover="entername()"> </p>
</main>
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this look helpful ?

```js
function entername() {
  var user = document.getElementById("username").value;
  document.querySelector('#content').innerText = "Hey " + user;
}

function overgreeting() {
  document.getElementById("content").style.backgroundColor = "green";
}
```

```html
<main>
  <input type="string" name="name" id="username">
  <button title="Greet" onclick="entername()">Greet</button>
  <button onmouseover="overgreeting()"> Test Button </button>
  <p id="content"> </p>
</main>
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the text you want to create and highlight within a `<div>` tag with its own id. Then reference the div element by id from your javascript code and apply the background color directly to div element. Depending on how this turns out you may want to have the div tag wrap content.

You could also define the div background color in a css and manage the disappearance and reappearance of the div element using the button.

Comment: OP is using a P tag. It almost works. If you have suggestions, copy the snippet to your editor and show what you mean...